# Pass data from service to controller AngularJS 1.3.15

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller

I have a big problem with sending data to my WorkspaceController.js from startingWebGazer service.
I have a webgazer.js which evaluate prediction points and pass it to xprediction and yprediction variables in StartingWebgazer.js(it is my service)

```
app.service('startingWebGazer', function () {
this.startgazer = function () {
    window.onload = function () {
        webgazer.setRegression('ridge') /* currently must set regression and tracker */
            .setTracker('clmtrackr')
            .setGazeListener(function (data, elapsedTime) {
                if (data == null) {
                    return
                }
                var xprediction = data.x; //these x coordinates are relative to the viewport
                console.log(xprediction);
                return xprediction;
                // var yprediction = data.y; //these y coordinates are relative to the viewport
            }).begin()
            .showPredictionPoints(true); /* shows a square every 100 milliseconds where current prediction is */
        var setup = function () {

            //Set up the main canvas. The main canvas is used to calibrate the webgazer.
            var canvas = document.getElementById("plotting_canvas");
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            canvas.style.position = 'fixed';
        };

        function checkIfReady() {
            if (webgazer.isReady()) {
                setup();
            } else {
                setTimeout(checkIfReady, 100);
            }
        }

        setTimeout(checkIfReady, 100);

    };


    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        console.log('user want to left the page');
        //webgazer.end(); //Uncomment if you want to save the data even if you reload the page.
        window.localStorage.clear(); //Comment out if you want to save data across different sessions
    }
}});
```

so, I want to pass xprediction to a WorkspaceController.js to do some evaluates in the future in the controller

```
app.controller('WorkspaceController', ['$scope', 'startingWebGazer', function ($scope, startingWebGazer) {
// create configuration object
$scope.startingWebGazer = startingWebGazer;
console.log($scope.startingWebGazer);
console.log('data in workspace', $scope.startingWebGazer.startgazer());}]);
```

but i have a big problem, because startgazer is undefined although xpreriction evaluate well(it is that console.log shows)
[image]

whhat is the problem? why I can see xprediction in console.log, but cant to pass it to the controller? and what I should to do?

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if i understand your problem correctly, but `startgazer` does not return a value the way it is defined. it assigns `window.onload` and `window.onbeforeunload` and then finishes without a return statement, which means that it returns `undefined`. you could consider assigning `xprediction` to a variable in the service scope and return that variable. i could imagine that something like that could serve your purpose:

```
app.service('startingWebGazer', function () {
    let x = 0;

    this.startgazer = function () {
        window.onload = function () {
            ...
            x = xprediction;
            ...
        }
        ...
    }

    this.getXPrediction = function() {
        return x;
    }
})
```

i think it would make sense to further refactor the code and e.g. call `startgazer` in a [run](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#run) method or make `getXPrediction` return a promise, but the example above could help you get started. hope it helps.